# Firebase Cloud Firestore doc.data().includes or .IndexOf doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to work with an array, trying to run `doc.data().includes` and `doc.data().indexOf` on the array I stored on the cloud firestore, the array is the only thing that exists in the doc.

The data is arranged like this

```
    0: example@gmail.com
    1: firebase@gmail.com
    2: new@gmail.com
```

To get to the data I just do

```
firebase.firestore().collection('mails').doc('emails').get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log(doc.data()); //prints the list of emails in form of array
                doc.data().IndexOf(email); //error IndexOf doesn't exist
                doc.data().includes(email); //error includesOf doesn't exist
            }
            else {
                console.log('data doesn't exist');

            }

        });
```

[image: The View of the Cloud Firestore Database]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the database (from the Firebase console)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec There you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you store your data **in an Array** and not as separate fields as shown by your Firestore database screenshot.

Your Firestore document currently contains 6 different fields and with `doc.data()` you retrieve all the 6 fields in this document as one JavaScript Object: this is why the Array methods cannot work. If you store this data in one Array (i.e. one field of type Array) it will be ok.

You can try the following code:

```
  const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('mails').doc('emails');

  docRef
    .set({
      mails: ['example@gmail.com', 'firebase@gmail.com', 'new@gmail.com'],
    })
    .then(() => {
      return docRef.get();
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        const email = 'example@gmail.com';
        console.log(doc.data().mails); 
        console.log(doc.data().mails.indexOf(email)); 
        console.log(doc.data().mails.includes(email)); 
      }
    });
```

Comment: that is a good answer and yes, usually I store information like that but then I stored this list just like this and was stuck with the object problem and I found a solution that can easily work with whatever existing data you have and I thought I should share what I did, just a little hack to overcome this problem, where you get object from firebase and you try running array operations on it

Answer (score 1):

To Get Access to `doc.data().IndexOf` or `doc.data().includes` or any other array related functions, just convert the `doc.data()` to array like this:

```
var docArray = Object.values(doc.data());
docArray.includes(stringToSearchFor);
```

or

`Object.values(doc.data()).includes(stringToSearchFor);`

this will allow you to run `docArray.includes` and `docArray.IndexOf`. Reason for converting is that firebase returns the entire doc which is an object of objects, you can see this by console.log(doc.data()) and seeing prototype field. This happens because firestore stores the array a json object meaning the array index numbers you see are not actually index numbers, they just object keys.

meaning

```
0: example@gmail.com
1: firebase@gmail.com
2: new@gmail.com
```

where `0, 1, 2` is the index( or as it seems) and `example@gmail.com, firebase@gmail.com, new@gmail.com` is value but in firestore that `0, 1, 2` is actually just keys, they are not index. So to get either the key(the numbers) or the values( the emails) we just run `Object.keys(doc.data())// will return numbers` or `Object.values(doc.data())//will return emails` and you will get array that you want and now you can run operations on this array.